# .Net Core 3.1 Process.Start("www.website.com") not working in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, process

I am using .Net Core 3.1 Framework in WPF Application. I have a button event in which I am trying to redirect to Instagram url on click. but its giving me the following error.

> Exception thrown: 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' in System.Diagnostics.Process.dll.

```
private void Insta_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string targetURL = "https://www.instagram.com/xyz/";
        Process.Start(targetURL);
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the exception message?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have to change you code per follows

```cs
var targetURL = "https://www.instagram.com/xyz/";
var psi = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = targetURL,
    UseShellExecute = true
};
Process.Start(psi);
```

[`UseShellExecute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute?view=netframework-4.8#property-value) property is set to `false` in .NET Core by default, to open `https://` link you have to set it to `true`, because it isn't an executable file

Comment: Thanks that solved my issue. I was missing UseShellExecute = true which I did not know about.