# Open file with Windows default Application

Tags: c#, pdf, .net-5

I am using C# .NET 5.0 to list PDF files on a folder and when double clicked on a item it opens the selected PDF with the windows default PDF viewer.
I've searched how to do this, but the solution code throws an exception.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\path\to\pdf\file.pdf");
```

Error:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.'
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true`, e.g. [Process.Start in Core 3.0 does not open a folder just by its name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58846709/7444103) -- [.Net Core 3.1 Process.Start("www.website.com") not working in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59716856/7444103)

Comment: do not worked...

Comment: You did something wrong or there's no Shell association to a PDF class. -- *Doesn't work* is not real information, it says nothing. You need to describe what you did and what specific error you got.

Comment: Sorry, but it thowed the same error...

Comment: Show us the code that you have tried, otherwise we could not help you further...

Answer (score 18):

Had this same issue when trying to open a excel spreadsheet.

.Net Framework used to have the UseShellExecute default to true, .Net 5.0 will default it to false.

In short, UseShellExecute as false it will use the CreateProcess instead of the ShellExecute and will have the same effect as running a command on your terminal.

By using the code below you should be able to run it as long as you have a program assotiated with that extension.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
psi.FileName = @"C:\path\to\pdf\file.pdf";
psi.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(psi);
```

If you don't want to do this way you can also specify what program binary to use and what file to open, for example you could use edge to open the PDF file like so:

```
Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe", @"C:\path\to\pdf\file.pdf");
```

Comment: Great. Now I understand... Thanks.

Comment: I had to add this line too: psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\path\to\pdf" (otherwise the program will use the executable path dir...)